# Why loop does not insert a value?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

Here is the link for the dataset https://www.dropbox.com/s/mcukuvpnrqrtgfd/datasetfirm.csv?dl=0 . I tried to loop for the dataset with the lags and leads using i+1 and i-1, i-2. When getting the results I see that i-1 and i-2 are working well, however, for the i+1 there is no result.

Here are the codes I used

```
datasetfirm<-read.csv("path")
datasetfirm<-datasetfirm[-1]


for (i in 1:nrow(datasetfirm)) {
  if (datasetfirm[i,4]==1){

    datasetfirm[i+1,5]<-55
    datasetfirm[i,5]<-1  
    datasetfirm[i-1,5]<-1
    datasetfirm[i-2,5]<-1


  }else{datasetfirm[i,5]<-7}

}
```

The expected result is that in the 5th column rows from 3 till 6 should be equal to 1 while with this code only 3 till 5 are 1.

Comment: it does not work. Waiting for the help

Comment: can you give your dataset using dput(datasetfirm) and copy/paste the output here

Comment: datasetfirm <- data.frame(CIKCode = c(8146, 8146,8146,8146,8146,8146,8146),
                 year = c(2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017,2018),
                 BODmarketing = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,1),
                 treatment = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1,0,0))    by now i-2 is also not working,

Comment: What the point of datasetfirm[i+1,5]<-55 ? There should be no 55 at the end of the process right ?

Comment: Yeah, this is a mistake, it should be datasetfirm[i+1,5]<-1, but this one does not work. At the end i will only select those rows , which are equal to one (3 till 6)

Comment: This is not working because of your else{...}. When i = 5 the loop set datasetfirm[6,5] <- 1. But at the next iteration  i = 6, so the loop goes to else{datasetfirm[6,5] <- 7}.